# Is It Possible to Upgrade From SharePoint 2010 to 2019?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, migration, 2019

Under Microsoft's "Upgrade and Update" documentation, I see guides for SharePoint 2010 to 2013 migration, as well as 2013/2016 to 2019 migrations,

But is it possible to upgrade directly from SP 2010 to SP 2019? If not, what is the best path to complete this upgrade?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three major options:

1. [Upgrade first](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-from-sharepoint2013-to-sharepointserver-2019) to 2013, and then to 2016, and then to 2019.
2. Use a third party tool to migrate sites and content from 2010 to 2019. There are quite a few tools that can do this, one is ShareGate.
3. Migrate manually. Train users how to manually copy files from the older environment into the new environment.

Answer (score 3):

The upgrade scenario has not changed in SharePoint Server 2019. There is no direct upgrade path from SP 2010 to SP 2019.

To upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019, you must upgrade SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Server 2013, then upgrade to SharePoint Server 2016, and finally upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019. Your databases must be at a SharePoint Server 2016 RTM version or higher when you upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019. Any database with a lower version will be locked and upgrade will not start.

(Microsoft supported upgrade path is DB Attach method for Site Collections)

There is no way to do this skipping a version unless you use a Third Party Migration tool like:

1. Sharegate
2. Metalogix
3. AvePoint
4. Vyapin Dockit Migrator